# How do I display data in random order from two loops in a Rails application?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code:

```
 <!-- Start of type 1 -->
<%@results.map do |p| %> 
    <li>
        <%= data1.p.url%>

    </li>
<%end%>
<!-- End of type 1 -->

<!-- Start of type 2 -->

<%@results.map do |p| %> 
    <li>
        <%= data2.p.url%>

    </li>
<%end%>
<!-- End of type 2 -->
```

Right now, the way it is being displayed is `data1 url` comes first and then `data2 url`. What I want to do is alternately, or randomly, display `data1 url` followed by `data2 url` or vice versa.

---

Update:

I wish to have the order of `<%= data1.p.url%>` and `<%= data2.p.url%>` displayed randomly on a single page request. That being said, if the user loads the page, the order of both the data is displayed randomly, without having to referesh multiple times to see one data (1 or 2) at a time.

---

Update2:

How would you make the order if the two loops are different?

```
<!-- Start of type 1 -->
<%@resultsOne.map do |p| %> 
    <li>
        <%= data1.p.url%>

    </li>
<%end%>
<!-- End of type 1 -->

<!-- Start of type 2 -->
<%@resultsTwo.map do |p| %> 
    <li>
        <%= data2.p.url%>

    </li>
<%end%>
<!-- End of type 2 -->
```

Comment: I was going to try to help make your question more readable, but your title has nothing to do with the question, and the question needs to be cleaned up. Remove the top section down to the "Update:...". There's no reason to leave unrelated material. Keep your question concise and clear -- remember, the people you're asking to help you are volunteers and doing this in their spare time, so don't waste it with unnecessary stuff.

Comment: hi @theTinMan , thanks for explaining. I understand it now. Have made the changes. Hopefully its clear and simple to understand now.

Comment: please precice your question.. if you mean the order, then please tell it

Comment: yes I mean the order. I have updated the question.

Comment: It's much more readable, and, more importantly, more understandable. Stack Overflow is trying to be like the Wikipedia of code Q&A. They like easily understood questions that lay out the problem clearly, allowing us to give useful answers. I reformatted it a little for readability and rephrased a few things for clarity.

Comment: Awesome. thanks much @theTinMan. Btw, do you would I randomize the order of the type1 and type2 code blocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like this?

```
<%@results.map do |p| %> 
    <li>
        <%= rand(2) == 0 ? data1.p.url : data2.p.url %>
    </li>
<%end%>
```

Comment: nope doesnt work. Only shows the part before `else`. And rand(1) == 0 is always true anyways, so i dont think it would actually look for the part after else

Comment: I realized i was doing it the wrong way.  I have updated the code above. let me know. sorry and thanks :)

Comment: i tried that. But now the part after `<% else %>` gets displayed only.

Comment: rand(2) is producing random numbers (0 or 1).. so you have to reload the site more often and you will see it works

Comment: yes but i wish to have the content display randomly, one after the another on one single page request.

Comment: awesome thanks. I am curious as to how would you do if the loops are a little different. I have updated the question, answer if you are free :). Thanks again